# Android Studio 1.1.0 mass "cannot resolve symbol" error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have got unexpected reboot while working in Android studio.
Before the reboot project was ok. After the reboot I started getting "Cannot resolve symbol ..." almost on every improt in the project.

Project setup (jdk and android sdk) looks ok. Even more - git shows me that no project files were changed since last commit.
Gradle build on the project passes successfully.

Android studio version is 1.1.0 (latest by now)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finaly helped me. I am listing all my steps just in case.

Full uninstall of Android Studio
Deleting all AndroidStudio settings folders (in Documents And Settings) 
Deleting Android and Gradle chache folders (in Documents And Settings .android and .gradle folders) - just in case
Fresh install of Android Studio and re-import of my project

The issue was completely gone.

What *didn't* help me before that:
Clean/rebuild/make the project
Checking all project and IDE settings
Updating Android SDK and Build tools

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to go: "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option.

My android studios shut down during a power failure and on restart I experienced this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Simon. I will try it if I meet the issue next time!

Answer (score 0):

Clean, Rebuild and Make Project. Sometimes Android Studio goes crazy.